# Perl: undefined subroutine

Tags: perl

```
my $pool = AnyEvent::Fork
    ->new
    ->AnyEvent::Fork::Pool::run(
    "worker",
    max => 4,
    idle => 2,
    load => 1,
    ); 


sub worker {
    #что-то делает
}
```

пишу сервер на перле. мне нужно, чтобы создавался динамический пул, обслуживающий запросы от клиентов. но при попытке запустить функцию в подпроцессе выдает ошибку Undefined subroutine &main::worker called at /home/------/lib/perl5/AnyEvent/Fork/RPC/Sync.pm line 53. Как это undefined, если функция определена в том же файле?

Comment: А в каком файле это у вас это написано, прямо в той .pl, которую запускаете и вы при этом никакой package не объявляли ?

Comment: да, в том же самом. я совсем новичок в перле, package не объявлял. пытался переносить в другой модуль, но не получилось, так как в worker передается $client=$server->accept, но при попытке чтения из этого клиента в воркере, говорит, что client uninitialized

Comment: тогда это очень странно. А что происходит если забить на AnyEvent и просто попробовать вызвать `main::worker()`. У меня ощущение, что package все таки присутствует и worker находится в итоге не в main::

Comment: при простом вызове worker или main::worker, все срабатывает...

Comment: Тогда у меня подозрение, что этот Fork как то умудряется сменить контекст процесса и вашего main в нем уже нет. Может именно по этому во всех примерах его использования функция обработчик находится в отдельном пакете и он явно подключается `AnyEvent::Fork->new->require()...`

Comment: Наверно что-то такое и происходит... Тогда возникает вопрос, как передать функции из другого модуля переменные типа клиента и condvar?

Comment: Я порыл исходники. Да, именно это и происходит. Там в new_exec можно увидеть что ищется текущий интерпретатор perl и потом он запускается отдельно на выполнение с передачей необходимого кода.

Comment: В примерах condvar передается Fork->run как параметр. Что то мне подсказывает, что в этом случае он ретранслирует события по ней из потомков в основной процесс. Но это опять же надо внимательно исходники смотреть. С передачей переменных явная проблема. Если это некий "тип клиента", то я бы эти типы сделал бы отдельными функциями в нужном пакете и соответственно передавал бы прямо их имя MyPackage::work1

Comment: спасибо за помощь, Mike! По крайней мере, теперь понятно, в чем проблема)